# What is the logic behind the radiotimer_start() C function?

Tags: c, embedded, msp430

Lines 50 - 69 in [radiotimer.c](https://github.com/openwsn-berkeley/openwsn-fw/blob/develop/firmware/openos/bsp/boards/gina/radiotimer.c) represent a function called "radiotimer_start()".

This function, if I understand correctly, is written for an [MSP430 x26x](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau144j/slau144j.pdf) hardware.

At an abstract level, this function starts a timer that (I believe) executes periodically (the parameter passed in).  But I am not able to understand at all how this works.

I was wondering if one of the experts from the community could please explain to me what is going on in each line of this function.

For example on line 61:

```
TACCTL2  =  CAP+SCS+CCIS1+CM_1;
```

Why is it adding so many values, and what is "capture mode"?

To be honest this entire function means nothing to me.

I would greatly appreciate it if one of the experts from the community could at least shed some light on how to figure out what any of these lines of code are doing, and possibly relate it to how a timer is started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That register is just setting a bunch of bits in it. The + is essentially an OR in this case. The statement can be rewritten as:

```
TACCTL2  =  CAP | SCS | CCIS1 | CM_1;
```

The info for each #define (CAP, SCS, CCIS1, and CM_1) should be in the libraries you are using. bits they set are shown on page 372 of the doc you linked.

CM_1 for example indicates capturing on the rising edge.

Comment: Thanks this is starting to make a little bit more sense.  So basically you're saying you just OR flags that you are interested in capturing, like CM_1.  What is TACCTL2 ?

Comment: It's a compare/capture control register.
http://www.mikroe.com/chapters/view/6/
That will give you a basic idea. Basically all control registers control 1 or more things. It doesnt make sense for an on-off setting to take up all 16 bits of the register, so they only define certain bits for each setting.

Comment: user1068636: the left side of the `=` is a control register. It is a place in the micro-controller's electronics where writing different values have different effects. In that case, different _bits_ of the register have different effects. E.g. set the bit `CAP` of register `TACCTL2` to 1 to setup the timer A compare/capture peripheral to capture mode (as opposed to compare mode). The right side of `=` says which bits to set to one, the `=` sign applies them to `TACCTL2`.

Comment: I dislike the practice of using `+` instead of `|`. This is no logical addition, and since using `+=` in place of `|=` does not work for setting bits, I can only see `|` as superior. Furthermore if you happen to have two bit definitions that actually are the same bit, you're in for troubles.